# Find min and max year in api response and loop through in ranges

Tags: php, api

I have an API which return `[period]` along all other values. Example:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [total] => 9000
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [period] => 2021
                    [productId] => 57
                    [value] => 0
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [period] => 2021
                    [productId] => 57
                    [value] => 123
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [period] => 2015
                    [productId] => 57
                    [value] => 153,35
                )
            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [period] => 1979
                    [productId] => 57
                    [value] => 153,35
                )
```

What I want to do is to find `min` and `max` year and then loop through the years in portions in 20 years span. After that update database records that I already have.

For example the min year above is 1979 and max year is 2021. This will give me 3 ranges of 20 years - 1979 - 1999 / 2000 - 2020 / 2021 -

What I have so far is

```
val = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= $response->total; $i++) {
    $val[] = $response->data->period;
}       

$min = min($val);
$max = max($val);
```

Here I'm trying to loop results until reach the `[total]` in order to get `min` and `max` periods but what is happening is that it takes lots of time > 5min for 9000 results.

The question is: Is it better to loop trough the results based on the `total` or on ranges as of years how I trying to do it? Is it better at all to loop on portions with some sleep between portions in order to not get time out on the page?

Update: pastebin with the code (sorry had to strip some information due to confidentiality but this is the main part that do the work): https://pastebin.com/Sa2S8SLX

Update: Debug info

Started on

> finished do.while and curl calls in 3.50371694565 seconds, caclled curl 1 times, allData size is 7 response total is 9517 finished first update in time_lapfinished foreach in 0.434380054474 seconds

Ended on

> finished do.while and curl calls in 0.608150005341 seconds, caclled curl 1 times, allData size is 7 response total is 9517 finished the main cycle in 140.772567034 secondscycle exec 203 times

Comment: What I can suggest, 1. try to use `foreach($response->data as $k => $v)`, and 2. avoid to create a new $val  array for this, that has to allocate memory 9000 times. You can use a form like `if ($v->period < $min) $min=$v->period`, same as $max; it's 16 bytest against 180k. Apart from that, 5 minutes for a 9000 element array looks excessive. Those should be fast operations anyway. You say 5 minutes JUST for this piece of code? I'll test on my PC.

Comment: @DanieleRugginenti, thanks. I guess the reason for the time running is because in the same time it's being stored in database. This results in another 9000 queries since the `UPDATE` is in the same loop.

Comment: Maybe if you showed us the real, complete code, 1) the question would be easier to understand and 2) A solution to the whole requirement would be easier to see as well

Comment: Weeeeellll ok... the updates are the slow part...
To manage that, create the array, create the update strings, open the DB channel, and execute the update at chunks of 1024 each one!

Comment: I will update my question with the whole code but since it is kinda long will put the pastebin

Comment: Updated with the pastebin

Comment: I updated my answer, as I suggest try to add some debug output and infos, to understand how many cycles all this code does. Nested cycles are always dangerous, if not perfectly controlled.

Comment: I updated the answer again.. If you need the API 203 times, and every call is ~0.6 seconds, 140seconds total it's quite a normal time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried on my laptop,

```
array size was 11403, max is 2021, min is 1979
exec time was 0.001971960067749 seconds
```

I used this array:

```
$arr = array(
    "total" => 11403,
    "data" => array (
        array ('period' => 2021, 'productId' => 57, 'value' => 0 ), 
        array ('period' => 1979, 'productId' => 157, 'value' => 100 ), 
        array ('period' => 1981, 'productId' => 257, 'value' => 10 ), 
        array ('period' => 2000, 'productId' => 357, 'value' => 11.99 ), 
        array ('period' => 2010, 'productId' => 457, 'value' => 12.99 ), 
        array ('period' => 2011, 'productId' => 7, 'value' => 0.55 ),
```

I used this code:

```
$time_start = microtime(true);

$min=9999; $max=0;
foreach ($arr['data'] as $k => $v) {
    if ($v['period'] < $min) $min = $v['period'];
    if ($v['period'] > $max) $max = $v['period'];
}

$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
```

---

Update2, after answer update;

Ok.
I studied it a little bit, impossible to test without the API and the DB structure you have.

Anyway, I don't think it's just about the updates or the min/max extraction.

You need some output and timers to check this code, and see where it's slow.

Because I don't understand, ie, how php can goes out of the do...while cycle, if you have a response->total=9000, and the condition says to go out when response->total=1

So, add some

$i, $i++, echo, microtome, etc, like this

---

UPDATE 2

Ok, looks like you call the API (curl) 203 times, that's the slow part. Each time is ~0.6secods, so 140s total execution time is normal.

IF you need a different offset after every cycle, and every call is different, this time makes sense. Call an API 203 times it's normally slow.

IF NOT, and looks like this is the case because the 2 calls you posted return the same results number (9517),
Just put the API call before the while cycle, so
BEFORE, you call the API one time,
THEN, you update the 203 tables

It's quite hard to solve all this without knowing exactly your need and DB structure, etc...

```
    $allData = array();
    $offset = $response->response->total ?: 0;
    $response = getData($offset);
                
    foreach($response->response as $row1){
         $allData[] = $row1;
         $urlData = $row1->data;
                      
         if (!empty($urlData)) {
            array_push($allData, $urlData);
        }       
    }

    while($row = $DB->fetch_object($result)) {
        
        if($response->response->total > 0) {
 
            // delete previous data
            $query1 = "UPDATE $roler->data_table SET $roler->data_field = NULL WHERE country_id = $row->id";
            $DB->query($query1);

            foreach($response->response->data as $data) {                               
 
                /*$val = array();
                for ($i = 0; $i < $response->response->total; $i++) {
                    $val[] = $response->data->period;
                }       
 
                    $min = min($val);
                    $max = max($val);
 
                print_r($max);*/
                if($response->response->frequency == "A") {
                    if($data->value) {
                        $query = "UPDATE $roler->data_table SET $roler->data_field = $data->value WHERE year = $data->period AND country_id = $row->id LIMIT 1";
                    }
                }
            }
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added pastebin with the code to the question. Can you advise how can I optimize the update queries?

Comment: Updated the question with first lap and last one from the DEBUG info. About the other issues - yes, aware of that. Will be done once this is done because is more important since the API will be stopped soon and new version will replace it. And this page is not accessible to the outside world anyway so no one can use it beside us.

Comment: Thanks but for some reason when I put it before while cycle it goes in infinity loop. Running through results over and over.